# How can I POST or GET to the same admin page from which I am POST-ing or GET-ing

Tags: admin, admin-menu, options

I have made a admin page linked to a Settings -> submenu_item. This page looks like this:

```
http://movahon.dev/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=miama-google-recaptcha%2Fmiama-google-recaptcha.php
```

On this page, I have a form which I want to submit to this same page. How can I do this? It is a bit of complication, since this page already has GET parameters in its URL, in form of the query string. So, I couldn't POST or GET to it easy, because it just redirects to the base URL, which is:

```
http://movahon.dev/wp-admin/options-general.php
```

I tried putting these in action, and none worked for me:

```
action="" 
action="#" 
action="<?php echo($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"
```

Answer (score 2):

While WP is a little weak about working with forms in general, there are some loose conventions that can help keep things organized.

For POST forms there is a dedicated `wp-admin/admin-post.php` endpoint, which meant for just that and works similarly to better known `admin-ajax.php`.

Unless you have good reasons to organize it otherwise I would recommend just to use it for form processing. After you are done you can get back to your page with something like `wp_safe_redirect( wp_get_referer() ); die;`.

Comment: +1 Almost a decade & I never knew about `admin-post.php`